# Components and Centralisers of Involution. A wrong argument?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A [component](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_%28group_theory%29) $K$ in a finite $G$ is a subnormal subgroup which is quasisimple, i.e. perfect and $K/Z(K)$ is simple. Obviously, when $K$ is a component of $G$ and $U\le G$, then $K$ is also a component of $U$. Further the following holds:

> If $K_1, K_2$ are two components of $G$, then $K_1 = K_2$ or $[K_1,K_2] = 1$.

Now I am trying to solve the following exercise:

> Let $t$ be an involution of $G$ and $E$ a component of $C_G(t)$. Then $E$ normalizes every component of $G$.

I guess the solution is quite simple, as if $K$ is a component of $G$, then it is also a component of $C_G(t)$, and therefore with the above either $E = K$ or $[E,K] = 1$, in either case $E \subseteq N_G(K)$?

I cannot see where the above argument is wrong, but it must be wrong as it is too simple, nowhere is used that the subgroup under consideration is the centraliser of an involution? What is wrong with the above argument?

Comment: You seem to be assuming that $K \le C_G(t)$.

Comment: Yes, thank you! Don't know why I was blind for this...

Comment: @StefanH did you figure out a proof of the result?