# Let $x$ be an involution in a group $G$ and $K$ be a component of $C_G(x)$. Show that $K$ normalizes every component of $G$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, involutions

The following is an exercise in Kurzweil and Stellmacher:

> Let $x$ be an involution in a finite group $G$, $K$ be a [component](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Component_(group_theory)#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20in%20the%20field,the%20layer%20of%20the%20group.) of $C_G(x)$ and $L$ be a component of $G$. Show that $K$ normalizes $L$.

Here, $E(G)$ is the [layer](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fitting_subgroup#The_generalized_Fitting_subgroup) of the group $G$.

---

**My attempt:** I first [showed](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4495540/let-x-be-an-involution-in-a-finite-group-g-and-k-be-a-component-of-c-gx) that either $K$ is a component of $G$ or $[K, C_{E(G)}(x)]=1$.

If $K$ is a component of $G$, then $K=L$ or $[K,L]=1$ and we're done.

In the other case, I showed that $gg^x\in C_{E(G)}(x)$ for all $g\in L$. Thus, $(LL^x)^k=LL^x$ for all $k\in K$.

> But how to show that $L^k=L$ for all $k\in K$?

PS: My question is not a duplicate of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1228360/components-and-centralisers-of-involution-a-wrong-argument) because there StefanH asks for the mistake in his (wrong) argument.

Comment: It would be helpful if you told us which exercise this is. Exercises in books are usually a lot easier if you know something about the context, previous exercises, etc. Also, your attempt includes the undefined symbol $t$.

Comment: @DerekHolt Sure, this is exercise 6.5.2 on Page 145.

Comment: Well if $(LL^x)^k=LL^x$, then $k$ must either normalize $L$ and $L^x$ or interchange them. But $K$ is perfect, so it has no subgroup of index $2$, so $K$ must normalize $L$ and $L^x$.

Comment: @DerekHolt What do you mean by interchange them,  $L^K = L^x$?

Comment: I said $k$ (not $K$) must normalize or interchange them, which means $K^x = K^k$ and $(K^x)^k = K$. Remember that elements of $G$ permute the components of $G$ under the conjugation action.

Comment: @DerekHolt Ah, so if $L$ and $L^x$ are distinct, then $LL^x$ is a direct product. So, $L^k\subseteq LL^x$ and $L^k\neq L$ implies that $L^k= L^x$!

Comment: If $L \ne L^x$, then $LL^x$ is not necessarily a direct product, but we have $L \cap L^x \le Z(L)$. It is called a central product.

Comment: @DerekHolt Let $H=N_G(L)\cap K$. Then $k\notin L$ but $k^2\in L$. Therefore, $\langle k\rangle/H$ is a subgroup of $K/H$ of index $2$. Hence, By third isomorphism theorem, $\langle k\rangle$ is a subgroup of $K$ of index $2$. Is this argument correct/ is there a simpler way to show that $K$ has a subgroup of index $2$?

Comment: I can't make much sense of what you write. Why should we have $k^2 \in L$? I would explain it like this: Conjugation is inducing an action of $K$ on $\{L, L^x\}$, and $H$ is the kernel of that action. Since the image of the action has order $1$ or $2$, $H$ has index $1$ or $2$ in $K$. But it cannot have index $2$, because $K$ is perfect.

Comment: I didn't say $k^2\in L$. I said $k^2\in H$ because $k^2\in N_G(L)$. However, your argument is much less complicated. Thanks! If you turn your second comment into an answer, I'll accept it.